# Can I write an npm run script to automate an ftp load to my server?

Tags: npm, ftp, svelte

In VSCode I'm using ftp-simple to upload a directory of static files from a Svelte site.

I would like to automate this, presumably using npm, so that when I run `npm run build` it also uploads the build folder to the specified ftp.

What can I use for this? `ftp-deploy` seems likely, but I'm not sure how to configure `package.json` etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) explains. Briefly, though:

In `package.json`, find (or create) the `scripts` property. Find or add a `build` property to that. The value should be the command required to upload. That can be a script that you write (using `ftp-deploy` or something else) or it can be a CLI tool that is installed as a dev dependency or a regular command or set of commands available to your shell.

So you might end up with something like this (but it probably won't be this exactly):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "myAwesomeFtpDeployScript.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Trott, this is how far I've already gone, I haven't yet built the mental model for understanding scripting in this way. But, as ever, starting with the documentation is best...!